# C# WPF Selenium3 with Geckofx newest Version

Tags: c#, wpf, selenium, geckofx, selenium3

Hi what I like to do is:

1. Create in WPF xaml a Grid like that: <_Grid Name="gridWeb">
2. Open a GeckoFX45 Firefox Browser in this Grid (add the created Geckofx Window as Child to the grid)
3. Automate this exact Browser in my Grid with Selenium.

I have made a lot of researches on that Problem and I found some articles like https://nhabuiduc.wordpress.com/2014/09/18/geckofx-net-webbrowser-setup-and-features/ on how to solve my issue. With that article I had success to solve point 1 and 2 but with old Version of Geckofx.

I have tried out tons of things, but nothing which included all requirements for my Tool.

Does anyone know if this is even possible?
If yes, does anyone know on how to combine all those 3 requirements with an actual version of Geckofx 45?

Comment: What is not working, man? What is the problem, what is you code?
The only real question I see is 'if this is even possible?' <- Yes, it is possible.

Comment: I have successfully opened Firefox via Geckofx, and also add it to my Grid in WPF. But I dont find any possibility to add this Webbrowser to Selenium IWebDriver. My Code is the same as in my Link posted.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reasony why you want to add this browser to Selenium IWebDriver? (like e.g. lots existing code written for IWebDriver?)

If not and you simply want to have an automated browser then you can do much more automation using GeckoFx API.

For example:

```
GeckoWebBrowser Browser => GetBrowserInstanceSomehow();

...
//get element reference 
GeckoInputElement textBox = 
this.Browser.Document.GetElementsByClassName("inputBox").FirstOrDefault() as GeckoInputElement; 

//set value
textBox.Value = "Something";

GeckoHtmlElement btn = this.Browser.Document.GetElementById("submitButton") as GeckoHtmlElement;

//interact
btn.Click();
```

You can do virtually everything with it - execute scripts, send POST requests, override CSS, evaluate / change / remove nodes, navigate, handle navigation events etc.

Comment: Yes sadly there is a particular reason why I need the Selenium IWebDriver, since I have written lots of code for an Automation of a WebService and I would not like to rewrite it for the GeckoBrowser. Also I want to update all my Firefox(at the moment my tool uses Firefox 46) and integrate it directly into it, because opening an external window does not look professional at all in my opinion. Sadly I haven't found any example code for that. And all tries resulted in not working at all.

Comment: I will do that, Thank you